# Слайдер Аккордеон jQuery

Tags: jquery

Посоветуйте слайдер Аккордеон jQuery?
И нет, не надо отправлять меня в гугл, я умею пользоваться  поисковиком, но прошу именно посоветовать то , что вам показалось хорошим и удобным на основании личного опыта ;)

Answer (score 4):

Как говорится: "На вкус и цвет - фломастеры разные". Если вам важны чужие мнения, то зайдите на [этот сайт](http://www.htmldrive.net/search?q=accordion&yt2.x=0&yt2.y=0). Рядом с каждым вариантом, есть количество одобрений в пользу этого плагина.

Comment: ещё один ресурс, где можно оценить и посмотреть другие оценки плагинов: [Plugin Detector](http://plugindetector.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Наверно будет сказано не полностью в тему, но если ты пользовал уже все "из гугла", то попробуй сделать свой. Будет наверно даже еще лучше чужого мнения, + опыт для себя

Comment: не, мне нужен готовый)